# Where i find and download this jar file com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver?

Tags: java, jdbc, classnotfoundexception, google-cloud-sql

I am working with Jdbc and CloudSql I followed this tutorial **https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/** when i Load this class  `com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver` by using `class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");`

I got

```
ClassNotFoundException
```

any one tell me where i download this jar?

Comment: I added this Jar in my classpath mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd use the com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver driver only when running your application on AppEngine.

Is that the case? If so, have you enabled mysql connector/j per https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#Java_Connect_to_your_database?

If you're running your application locally, you'd want to use the stock mysql driver.

Comment: Admittedly a little vague what does that driver do any differently, as opposed to or in addition to what the stock driver (which is used for accessing the cloud database from a local machine) does.

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting this exception after deployment? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644148/java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-load-jdbc-driver-class-com-mysql-jdb