# Connecting to Cloud SQL from Dataflow Job

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm struggling to use JdbcIO with Apache Beam 2.0 (Java) to connect to a Cloud SQL instance from Dataflow within the same project.

I'm getting the following error:

```java
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
```

- According to the documentation the dataflow service account *@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com should have access to all resources within the same project if he's got "Editor" permissions.
- When I run the same Dataflow job with DirectRunner everything works fine.

This is the code I'm using:

```java
private static String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://myip:3306/mydb?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true";

PCollection < KV < String, Double >> exchangeRates = p.apply(JdbcIO. < KV < String, Double >> read()
 .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", JDBC_URL)
  .withUsername(JDBC_USER).withPassword(JDBC_PW))
 .withQuery(
  "SELECT CurrencyCode, ExchangeRate FROM mydb.mytable")
 .withCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), DoubleCoder.of()))
 .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper < KV < String, Double >> () {
  public KV < String, Double > mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
   return KV.of(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getDouble(2));
  }
 }));
```

**EDIT:**

Using the following approach outside of beam within another dataflow job seems to work fine with DataflowRunner which tells me that the database might not be the problem.

```java
java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, JDBC_USER, JDBC_PW);
```

Answer (score 7):

Following these instructions on how to connect to Cloud SQL from Java:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#java

I managed to make it work.

This is what the code looks like (you must replace MYDBNAME, MYSQLINSTANCE, USER and PASSWORD with your values.

**Heads up**: MYSQLINSTANCE format is project:zone:instancename.

And I'm using a custom class (Customer) to store the values for each row, instead of key-value pairs.

```
p.apply(JdbcIO. <Customer> read()
    .withDataSourceConfiguration(
        JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
            "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", 
            "jdbc:mysql://google/MYDBNAME?cloudSqlInstance=MYSQLINSTANCE&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=USER&password=PASSWORD&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
        )
    )
    .withQuery( "SELECT CustomerId, Name, Location, Email FROM Customers" )
    .withCoder( AvroCoder.of(Customer.class) )
    .withRowMapper(
        new JdbcIO.RowMapper < Customer > ()
        {
            @Override
            public Customer mapRow(java.sql.ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception
            {
                final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CloudSqlToBq.class);
                LOG.info(resultSet.getString(2));
                Customer customer = new Customer(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getString(2), resultSet.getString(3), resultSet.getString(3));
                return customer;
            }
        }
    )
);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just curious, how would the `Customer` class look like? Would it be something like a `JavaBean` class?

Answer (score 3):

Hi it worked for me in the way u did it.Additionaly i removed withusername and password methods from the db configuration method and my pipeline configurations looks like below

```
PCollection < KV <  Double, Double >> exchangeRates = p.apply(JdbcIO. < KV <  Double, Double >> read()
     .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/dbname?user=root&password=root&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8")
             )
     .withQuery(
      "SELECT PERIOD_YEAR, PERIOD_YEAR FROM SALE")
     .withCoder(KvCoder.of(DoubleCoder.of(), DoubleCoder.of()))
     .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper < KV < Double, Double >> () {
      @Override
       public KV<Double, Double> mapRow(java.sql.ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
         LOG.info(resultSet.getDouble(1)+ "Came");
          return KV.of(resultSet.getDouble(1), resultSet.getDouble(2));
      }
     }));
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

I think this approach may work better, please try the com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver, and use the maven dependencies listed here.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/#Java_Connect_to_your_database

Related question:
[Where i find and download this jar file com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829110/where-i-find-and-download-this-jar-file-com-mysql-jdbc-googledriver)

Comment: Hey @alex-amato, unfortunately that doesn't seem to work with gcp dataflow as I get a "java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver'" error even though both maven dependencies are added.